# LibreOffice not starting

Tags: libreoffice

Mates.
I was working with a pdf on Drawer, LibreOffice crashed and didn't came back to work.

When I try to load it from the console i get this error:

```
libreoffice
UNO Exception: InvalidRegistryException: file:///usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../share/extensions/pdfimport/components.rdb: 
duplicate <implementation name="com.sun.star.comp.documents.HybridPDFImport">
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::DeploymentException'
```

I've tried uninstalling and installing back.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OPs comment

> I solved it!
>
> I've renamed extensions folder under `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share`, and
>   it came back. Gotta see if the pdf extensions is still working, but
>   now at least I can run LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

See what's in your `./libreoffice/program/share/extensions` after uninstalling/reinstalling. Good luck bud!

else, you could check this out: [Bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51252)

Comment: I don't have any libreoffice folder on my home directory

Comment: It is a hidden folder. Press ctrl + h to show hidden files and folders starting with a dot.

Comment: I know, but I don't have a libreoffice folder

Comment: I looked under /usr/share/libreoffice/share/, and there's no extensions folder

Answer (score 0):

Use Synaptic package manager and search for openoffice-pdfimport and mark it to be removed and apply Libre Office started up immediately! Though in Software Center / History
It showed I removed libreoffice-pdfimport(1.0.6+lib03.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4)